# Can a static member be overloaded?

Tags: f#

```
type A() =
    static member B() = ()
    static member B(x) = B() //ERROR: The value or constructor 'B' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When refering to a static member in F#, you need to use the full name (including the name of the type). The F# compiler doesn't automatically look for static members of the current class.

The following should work:

```
type A() = 
    static member B() = () 
    static member B(x) = A.B()
```